# Updating the @INC variable during installation of a conda package

Tags: perl, environment-variables, conda, environment, conda-build

I am trying to install a conda package of a Perl module. So far I'm able to create the package using `conda-build`. For that I have a recipe containing a `build.sh` and a `meta.yaml` files.

I then install it using `conda-install` in a new environment, I'd like to be able able to run some Perl scripts located in the Perl module I just installed.

All those steps work well but when I'm running some scripts I have an error saying :

`Can't locate PMP/util.pm in @INC (you may need to install the PMP::util module) (@INC contains: /.autofs/home/antoine/anaconda2/envs/testCustomChannel/lib/site_perl/5.26.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /.autofs/home/antoine/anaconda2/envs/testCustomChannel/lib/site_perl/5.26.2 /.autofs/home/antoine/anaconda2/envs/testCustomChannel/lib/5.26.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /.autofs/home/antoine/anaconda2/envs/testCustomChannel/lib/5.26.2 .)`

As you can see it seems that some module of my Perl module are not recognized when I execute Perl. I know that to fix this issue I can modify the @INC variable and add the bin/ to the PATH and the lib/ to the PERL5LIB but I need to automatize this process during the installation of the module.

I don't really know where I should modify the environment variable. During the creation of the package by adding something in the `build.sh` for example ? Or should I manage that during the installation and if so, how could I do that ?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated,

Thanks

**Edit :**

**meta.yaml =>**

```
{% set name = "module_name" %}
{% set version = "0.8.3" %}

package:
  name: "{{ name }}"
  version: "{{ version }}"

source:
  git_url: ssh://git@adress/bspcore/perl_module.git

build:
  number: 0

requirements:
  host:
    - perl
    - perl-extutils-makemaker
  run:
    - perl

about:
  home: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  license: xxx
  license_family: xxx
  summary: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

**Build.sh =>**

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -f Build.PL ]; then
    perl Build.PL
    perl ./Build
    # Make sure this goes in site
    perl ./Build install --installdirs site
elif [ -f Makefile.PL ]; then
    # Make sure this goes in site
    perl Makefile.PL INSTALLDIRS=site
    make
    make install
else
    echo 'Unable to find Build.PL or Makefile.PL. You need to modify build.sh.'
    exit 1
fi

chmod u+rwx $PREFIX/bin/*
echo "${PREFIX}"
```

**Edit 2 :**

Another edit that could help you guys understand better my situation. I just realized that when I build the package the lib folder of my perl module in which I have `PMP::util` lives under `lib/site_perl/5.26.0/Perl_Module`. I'm pretty sure that if I'm able to install it directly under the `lib/` folder it will resolve this issue. However I'm not sure how to modify the build.sh file to modify the place where we build the perl module.

Comment: How did you install the perl 5.26.2? Which scripts are you running? How are you running them?

Comment: Perl installation : In the meta.yaml, I have `-perl` in my requirements `run/host` field.

I run a test located in the t/ folder of my perl module. And I call it by running : `perl <path_to_my_script.t>`.

PS : I'm gonna edit my question to add the build.sh and the meta.yaml file :)

Comment: Thanks for the update. I have not used `conda` before, but I would like to try it out. Can I download the conda package that you have created from somewhere? Then I can try install it on my machine

Comment: I would have love to, but it's a perl module from my company. I can't share it to anyone...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple example of how to create a conda package that installs a Perl module (which depends on a CPAN module) that might help you solve your issue:

### Installing miniconda on Linux

```
$ wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
$ bash Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
# NOTE: I answered "yes" on the question:
#   "Do you wish the installer to initialize Miniconda3 ?" in the
#   previous command. This will modify ~/.bashrc
$ source ~/.bashrc # activates base environment
# Next command: Do not automatically activate conda for every terminal window,
# instead run "conda activate" from a given terminal window to
# activate locally. The following command also creates ~/.condarc
$ conda config --set auto_activate_base False
```

### Creating the package:

**perl-hello/meta.yaml**:

```
package:
  name: perl-hello3
  version: "1.0"

source:
  path: ../src # NOTE: if you had put "src" in same folder as "meta.yaml", 
               # conda-build would have include the src folder in info/recipe in 
               # the generated package. It is not necessary to include  the 
               # source code in the generated package.

requirements:
  build:
    - perl >= 5.22
    - make

  run:
    - perl >= 5.22

about:
  license: Artistic
  summary: Simple perl function
```

**../src/**:

```
$ tree ../src
../src
├── lib
│   └── My
│       └── Module.pm
└── Makefile.PL
```

**../src/Makefile.PL**:

```
use utf8;
use ExtUtils::MakeMaker;

WriteMakefile(
    MIN_PERL_VERSION => 5.022000,
    NAME             => 'My::Module',
    VERSION_FROM     => 'lib/My/Module.pm',
    PREREQ_PM        =>
    {
        'ExtUtils::MakeMaker' => '7.12',
        'Data::Dump'          => 0,
    },
    ABSTRACT_FROM    => 'lib/My/Module.pm',
    AUTHOR           => 'Håkon Hægland <hakon.hagland@gmail.com>',
    LICENSE          => 'perl',
);
```

**../src/lib/My/Module.pm**:

```
package My::Module;
our $VERSION = 0.01;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Exporter qw(import);

our @EXPORT = qw(hello);
our @EXPORT_OK = @EXPORT;

use Data::Dump;
sub hello {
    print "Hello world!\n";
    my $str = "Testing Perl module Data::Dump";
    dd $str;
}
1;
```

**build.sh**:

```
# PERL_MM_USE_DEFAULT=1  -> automatically answer "yes" on config questions
PERL_MM_USE_DEFAULT=1 cpan App::cpanminus
perl ${PREFIX}/bin/cpanm Data::Dump
perl Makefile.PL INSTALLDIRS=site
make
make install
```

Note that I ran `cpanm` using `perl ${PREFIX}/bin/cpanm`. I was not able to simply run it as `cpanm`, see [Can you rely on the shebang of an installed command during build?](https://github.com/conda/conda-build/issues/3592) for more information.

### Build the package

```
$ conda-build .
```

(Take a note of the generated output, and determine the path of the generated package. In my case the path name was:

```
/home/hakon/miniconda3/conda-bld/linux-64/perl-hello3-1.0-pl526_0.tar.bz2
```

### Uploading the package to the anaconda server

- Register a new user at [Anaconda Cloud](https://anaconda.org/account/register)
- Install the client

  ```
  $ conda install anaconda-client
  ```
- Login to your account:

  ```
  $ anaconda login
  ```
- Upload the generated package:

  ```
  $ anaconda upload /home/hakon/miniconda3/conda-bld/linux-64/perl-hello3-1.0-pl526_0.tar.bz2
  ```

## Testing the package (can be done from any linux machine):

- Create a new enviroment:

  ```
   $ conda create --name perltest
   $ conda activate perltest
  ```
- Install the package in the new environment:

  ```
   $ conda install -c hakonhagland perl-hello3 
   # Alternatively: You can test the package locally before uploading with
   #   "conda install --use-local perl-hello3"
  ```
- Test the package:

  ```
   $ perl -E 'use My::Module; hello'
   Hello world!
   "Testing Perl module Data::Dump"
  ```

Comment: Hey,
Thank you for the time you take to help me with this issue. Your answer is very helpful ! I'll work around it to make my Perl module works.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand the `path : ../src`. I keep having an error like saying it cannot copy the content of my perl module. I tried to follow your example. I don't have this issue in my situation though because the source comes from GitHub :) However I still cannot make it work and I try to reproduce your little tutorial but it seems that you put the path of the perl module relative to the recipe folder right ?

Comment: By using `path: ../src` I avoid having the source incorporated in the generated conda package. If I instead had the `src` folder in the same folder as `build.sh`, and then used `path: src` in `meta.yaml`, `conda-build` would have included the `src` folder in `info/recipe` in the generated package.

Comment: @AntMau I have updated my answer to include installation from Anaconda Cloud. Now you could test my package using `conda install -c hakonhagland perl-hello3` if you like!

Comment: Hello, I come back to you again. I followed your tutorial to install the package from scratch. I had been able to do it but I can't locate `Data::Dumper in @INC`. First if in the build.sh I have `perl ${PREFIX}/bin/cpanm Data::Dump`, the build fails saying that the file `cpanm` doesn't exist. I looked and effectively I have a `cpan` script but not a `cpanm` script. The build is working tough if I have instead `perl ${PREFIX}/bin/cpan Data::Dump` but after that if I try to test the module by running `$ perl -E 'use My::Module; hello'`I have this error : `Can't locate Data/Dump.pm in @INC`

Comment: The module isn't installed I guess. The full error message is (I didn't have enough characters in the last comment) : `Can't locate Data/Dump.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Data::Dump module) (@INC contains: /home/antoine/anaconda2/envs/testPerlHello/lib/site_perl/5.26.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /home/antoine/anaconda2/envs/testPerlHello/lib/site_perl/5.26.2 /home/antoine/anaconda2/envs/testPerlHello/lib/5.26.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /home/antoine/anaconda2/envs/testPerlHello/lib/5.26.2 .) at /home/antoine/anaconda2/envs/testPerlHello/lib/site_perl/5.26.2/My/Module.pm line 10.`

Comment: *"I had been able to do it but I can't locate Data::Dumper in @INC"* : Note: it is `Data::Dump` not `Data::Dumper`...

Comment: Hi AntMau! *"the build fails saying that the file cpanm doesn't exist"* : The point is that the previous command in `build.sh`, i.e., this command  `PERL_MM_USE_DEFAULT=1 cpan App::cpanminus` installs the `cpanm` command in the `bin` folder, so it should exist if that command succeeded

Comment: Yes indeed I can't find `Data::Dump` not `Data::Dumper`. I see during the build an ?error? => `Running install for module 'App::cpanminus'
Checksum for /home/antoine/.cpan/sources/authors/id/M/MI/MIYAGAWA/App-cpanminus-1.7044.tar.gz ok
'YAML' not installed, will not store persistent state
Configuring M/MI/MIYAGAWA/App-cpanminus-1.7044.tar.gz with Makefile.PL
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Generating a Unix-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for App::cpanminus
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json`

Comment: And then => `MIYAGAWA/App-cpanminus-1.7044.tar.gz
  /.autofs$PREFIX/bin/perl Makefile.PL -- OK
Running make for M/MI/MIYAGAWA/App-cpanminus-1.7044.tar.gz
  MIYAGAWA/App-cpanminus-1.7044.tar.gz
  /home/antoine/anaconda2/conda-bld/perl-hello3_1563296734539/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehol/bin/make -- NOT OK`

Comment: It seems that make isn't find ? Then effectively the installation of cpanminus isn't complete ? Btw I have the same ?error? for the module Data::Dump

Comment: Can you send me the `build.sh` script you are using? My email is in my profile. Then I will have a look at it