# Install Perl modules using conda and App::cpanminus

Tags: perl, installation, module, conda, cpanm

I am using [`conda`](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/) where possible to install packages on Ubuntu and macOS. I keep packages in separate `conda` environments, to better manage dependencies. **How to install Perl plus common non-core Perl modules using `conda` as much as possible?** Obviously, I also need to use on top of `conda` something like [`App::cpanminus`](https://metacpan.org/pod/App::cpanminus) to [install specific modules](http://www.cpan.org/modules/INSTALL.html).

I have found this post: [Using cpanm to Install Perl Modules in a Conda Environment](https://dev.to/yzhernand/using-cpanm-to-install-perl-modules-in-a-conda-environment-5ae3) by Yozen Hernandez (Jun 30, 2020). So far, the methods listed there appear to work, for example:

```
# install Perl and the module App::cpanminus:
conda create -c bioconda --name perl526 perl-app-cpanminus
source activate perl526

# install Regexp::Common Perl module:
env PERL5LIB="" PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT="" PERL_MM_OPT="" PERL_MB_OPT="" cpanm Regexp::Common
source deactivate
```

**Are there simpler or more robust solutions?**

---

**Notes:**

I am aware that the `conda` Perl is several versions behind the most recent Perl version, and that `perl-app-cpanminus` is even more behind. For my applications, this is OK. I am creating bioinformatics workflows using [Nextflow](https://www.nextflow.io/) and [Galaxy](https://github.com/galaxyproject/galaxy/), where using `conda` as much as possible offers many advantages. Hence, I can tolerate the somewhat old Perl versions.

I am aware of the directions on [the main perl site](https://www.perl.org/get.html), which refer to [perlbrew](https://perlbrew.pl/), but I am interested in the `conda`-based solutions.

Comment: See also [Updating the @INC variable during installation of a conda package](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56875121/2173773)