# Perl conda recipe installation path

Tags: perl, conda, conda-build

I am packaging a perl library with conda. My conda recipe looks like so

```
package:
  name: <name>
  version: 1.0.0

source:
  git_url: <git_url>

build:
  script:
    - perl Makefile.PL INSTALLDIRS=site
    - make
    - make test
    - make install VERBINST=1

requirements:
  build:
    - make
    - {{ compiler('c') }}
  host:
    - perl
  run:
    - perl
```

the issue I am having is that when I build this with `conda build .` My perl packages get installed in the following path inside the package `$PACKAGE_ROOT/lib/site_perl/5.32.2/App/Options.pm`. When I install this into an environment `App::Options` is not on in my `@INC` path.

However, If I instead pin perl in the recipe like so `perl >= 5.32` then it installs in the path `$PACKAGE_ROOT/lib/perl5/site_perl/App/Options.pm` and I can install and use this in my environment.

I cannot find anything in the perl or conda documentation about why this would be and I am very confused.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/56898953/2173773